# MongoDB aggregate query equivalent to Ruby on Rails distinct query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongodb-query

Ruby on Rails distinct query returns array of unique values in specified field.

`User.distinct(:name)`

returns array of unique values in name field.

e.g. `['John', 'David', 'Steve']`

Looking out for an equivalent aggregate query (`User.collection.aggregate([])`) in MongoDB which would return an array of unique values in specified field.

Comment: see [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group) operator to group by null and use `$addToSet` on specific field

Comment: @Suhas User.distinct(:name) won't return an array of the uniquely specified field's value. it will return array of whole records.

Comment: @Vishal User.distinct(:name) does return array of unique values in specified field.

e.g.

`User.all.map(&:name) => ['John', 'David', 'John', 'Steve', 'David']`

but

`User.distinct(:name) => ['John', 'David', 'Steve']`

Comment: @turivishal as per your suggestion I tried using $group operator with $addToSet on specified field but it just returned empty array.
`User.collection.aggregate([{"$group" => {"_id" => nil, "array" => {"$addToSet" => "$name"}}}]) => []`

Comment: see working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nn4DKObBqm-), i don't know ruby syntax so i can't give query in ruby.